# how to use sas labeling

Tags: sas, label

trying to uses SAS Label like so, but not working. The output table still uses the inputs as variable names.

thank you

```
data names2;
    input id m1 m2;
    label id="id number" m1="first month" m2="second month";
datalines;
001 0 0 0 0
002 0 1 1 0
003 0 1 0 0
004 1 1 0 0
;
run;
```

Comment: Do you want Labels in the dataset or in the Proc Print?

Comment: Your program looks fine (other than ignoring the last two columns of data and the extra `run;` statement).  Explain what your problem is.

Comment: How are you viewing the 'output table` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct, in the menu options you have to select view "Column Labels" instead of the default "Column Names"

Answer (score 0):

`Proc PRINT`, by default, displays the column names (the variable name) in the column headers.  Use the `LABEL` option to view the labels

```
Proc PRINT data=have label;
run;
```

ViewTable, the default, displays column names (the variable name) in the column headers.  The menu action `View / Column Labels` will show the labels in the column headers.